# Simple way to average all elements of all vectors in a list using R

Tags: r, list, vector

I'm an R beginner. I have a list containing numerical vectors of differing lengths. I would like to find the average of all the entries in all the vectors (not the average of each vector). Is there a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple as this:

```
mean(unlist(yourlist))
```